# What particular way is this font styling?

Tags: css

I see this particular font css applied to

```
font: 400 50px/60px "minion-pro",times,serif;
```

an element. I want to understand what is 400 whats meaning of 50px/60px and which of the three fonts "minion",times or serif gets applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write like this:

```
div{
 font-weight:400;
 font-size:50px;
 line-height:60px;
 font-family:"minion-pro",times,serif;
}
```

In the **font-family** they are `fall back` fonts . fallBack fonts means if `"minion-pro"` is not in user computer then it's pick `times` instead of `"minion-pro"` & if there `times` is not in the user computer then it's pick `serif` font-family.

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten like this:

```
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 50px;
line-height: 60px;
font-family: "minion-pro",times,serif;
```

So `400` is the weight of the font, `50px/60px` means `50px` font size, with `60px` line-height. The first available font will be applied which exists on the computer which is displaying the webpage.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font

Answer (score 1):

This is the [shorthand `font` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand).

```
font: style variant weight size / height family1, family2,...;
```

is short for

```
font-style : style;
font-variant: variant;
font-weight: weight;
font-size: size;
line-height: height;
font-family: family1, family2,...;
```

The [`font-family`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) property takes a prioritized list:

> The property value is a prioritized list of font family names and/or generic family names

The browser will use the first font-family that's available. There are some generic names like `sans-serif`, `serif` and `monospace`.

**EDIT**: Also note that `font-weight:400` is the same as `font-weight: normal`.

See also:

- [W3C: CSS2.1: Fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can answer for the font, they'll be used by order of availability (some browser might not render them or know them) so 1st minion then times then serif. For the 400 I don't know at the moment